# Is there a possibility to use computer name instead of IP if I am in a different network/domain?

Tags: java, dns, ip

I have a list of computer names and I have to create a list of corresponding IP addresses. Which is done in a way like that:

```
        Iterator<String> iter = listWithComputerNames.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String curName = iter.next();
            String ipAdress = "";
            try {
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(curName );
                ipAdress = address.getHostAddress();
            }
        }
```

This works if I run the programm in the same domain as all the other computers. However, I would like to run in it as a batch job on a server, which is in a different domain (but still the same local network!).

Since both domains are within one company and computers can communicate with each other using IPs, I wonder whether there is a possibility to explicitly tell that my computer name is from a different domain: something like name.domain.local, such that it can be resolved to an IP even from a different domain. Does anyone know the trick?

Comment: Where you you get your list of computer names from? What do these names look like? Are they fully qualified names with domain names? If not, do they all exist in the same domain name, so that you can just append the domain name to each computer name?

Comment: You can do it the same way you populate listWithComputerNames, instead, you populate listWithComputerIps.

Comment: My colleagues provide me their computer names. We have tried both computer names and fully qualified names, but the server can not resolve them. @Karim I don't know the IPs, since they change over time, computer names do not.

Comment: I was kidding check my answer under it's a possible solution if the server can't access to a domain name

Answer (score 0):

```
InetAddress giriAddress = java.net.InetAddress.getByName("com.named.domain");
```

Then, if you want the IP as a String

```
String address = giriAddress.getHostAddress();
```

you can use this in your local env to update some kind of a database that the server then can access if he wants the IP address, or even better expose it as a web service

Comment: Unfortunately fully qualified names do not work neither.